# Передача данных между сервером и клиентом

Tags: java, сокет

Server

```
public static void activ(ServerSocket serverSocket) throws IOException {
    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
    InputStream sin =socket.getInputStream();
    OutputStream sout = socket.getOutputStream();
    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(new File("Log.txt"));
    InputStream sfin = new BufferedInputStream(fin);
    int res = IOUtils.copy(sfin, sout);
    fin.close();
    sfin.close();
    sout.flush();
    fin = new FileInputStream(new File("Client.png"));
    sfin = new BufferedInputStream(fin);
    res = IOUtils.copy(sfin, sout);
    sout.flush();
    sout.close();
    socket.close();
```

Client

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 15123);
    InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(new File("Log.txt"));
    OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(fout);
    int res = IOUtils.copy(in,out);
    out.close();
    out.flush();
    fout = new FileOutputStream(new File("Client.png"));
    out = new BufferedOutputStream(fout);
    res = IOUtils.copy(in,out);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    in.close();
    //bos.flush();
    //bos.close();
    socket.close();
}
```

}

Пытаюсь передать файлы, используя IOUtils.copy(), но столкнулся с такой проблемой, что программа все файлы складывает в один файл. 
 Приведу пример, чтобы было немного понятнее:
я пытаюсь передать 2 файла "Log.txt" и "Client.png". По завершению работы программы, эти 2 файла превращаются в один, т.е. перемешиваются. Кто знает как можно решить эту проблему?
Сам файл "Log.txt" выглядит следующим образом:

```
Update  /images Client.png  Small
Update  /images Close.png   Small
```

Но на выходе он мне выдаёт следующее:

```
Update  /images Client.png  Small
Update  /images Close.png   Small<содержимое Client.png>
```

Answer (score 0):

Перед передачей самого файла, передайте его длину (и пр информацию о файле - имя, дату создани и т.д.). Приемник считывает эту мета-информацию и создает файлы правильного размера, с правильными атрибутами.

Comment: А нельзя ли как-нибудь в серверной части указать, что передача данного файла закончена? Потому как раньше я просто передавал файлы без указания их размерности и всё работало, но это было пол года назад и я уже подзабыл про это.

Comment: вы можете закрыть канал. и для следующего файла снова его создать.

Comment: т.е. для каждого файла отдельно создавать канал? А если у меня список файлов?

Comment: @DmitryLin просто используйте мою идею.